# My code doesn't return anything from the wordlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a_file = open(r"C:\Users\lisin\Desktop\Code\Bomb Party\wordlist.txt", "r")

list_of_lists = []
for line in a_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  line_list = stripped_line.split()
  list_of_lists.append(line_list)

a_file.close()

wordlist = list_of_lists

contains = input("? ")

matches = [match for match in wordlist if str(contains) in match]

print(matches)
```

When I run the code and put any letters in, it returns nothing. The wordlist has it, but it is still not returning anything. I'm trying to get any word that contains what you input.

Edit: I was not very clear of want I wanted to create. want to be able to input a string, lets say "ee", and have it return any words that have "ee" in them, like "bee" or "free"

Fixed! It turns out it was making a list of lists and I did not realize that somehow. So I just converted the list into a string and then separated it into a list

```
def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li

with a_file as myfile:
    x = myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')
```

Sorry if I wasn't clear about what I wanted. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why `str(contains)` rather than just `contains`? You don't have to convert a string to a string. In any event, a [mcve] which doesn't depend upon a file that only you can access would be nice. If reading the wordlist isn't the problem --- just use a small literal wordlist in your posted code.

Comment: `wordlist` is a list of `line_list` items which in turn is a list of strings. In your matching code, you check if `contains` is contained in the list of lists, rather than in the strings.

Comment: "When I run the code and put any letters in, it returns nothing." Can you show an example of what you expect `wordlist` to look like, what you want to type for `contains`, and exactly what resulting `match`es should be detected? And explain the logic thereof? I cannot reproduce the problem; when I try your code with some example data and an example input, I get the result I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you fill `matches`. `match` is a list of string and not a string itself, this is why the condition is never fulfilled.

I assumed you wanted every occurrences of `contains` in `wordlist`. To resolve this, you want a list of coordinates as `(line, word)`. If I write it like you with `tuple` of `int`:

```py
matches = [(index_line, index_word) for index_line, line_list in enumerate(wordlist) for index_word, word in enumerate(line_list) if word == contains]
```

I think it's hard to read. I recommend this instead:

```py
matches = []
for index_line, line_list in enumerate(wordlist):
    for index_word, word in enumerate(line_list):
        if word == contains:
            matches.append((index_line, index_word))

print("Occurence(s) of the word can be found at :")
for match in matches:
    print(f"  Line {match[0]}, word {match[1]}")
```

You may also use a function:

```py
def matches(wordlist : list, contains : str) -> list:
    for index_line, line_list in enumerate(wordlist):
        for index_word, word in enumerate(line_list):
            if word == contains:
                yield (index_line, index_word)

print("Occurence(s) of the word can be found at :")
for match in matches(wordlist, contains):
    print(f"  Line {match[0]}, word {match[1]}")
```

`enumerate()` return two variables : the index of the element in the list, and the element itself. `yield` is harder to understand, it let you read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/17187588).

Input :

> Hello !
>
> My name is John
>
> And you ?
>
> John too !

`contains = "John"`

Output :

> Occurence(s) of the word can be found at :
>
> Line 2, word 4
>
> Line 4, word 1

Comment: This seems to be assuming way too much about what OP is trying to do. Please don't try to answer the question yet; it doesn't meet question-asking standards.

Comment: While this is working code, it's not exactly what I was asking. I want to be able to input a string, lets say "abc", and have it return any words that have "abc" in them